# What is the cost difference between querying from BigQuery and loading a file with the results from Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

We can query results in any language from Google BigQuery using the predefined methods `->` [see docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-overview).

Alternatively, we can also query the results and store them to cloud storage, for example in a .csv `->` [see docs on storing data to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries)

When we repeatedly need to extract the same data, eg lets say 100 times per day, does it make sense to cache the data to Cloud Storage and load it from there, or to redo the BigQuery requests?

What is more cost efficient and how would I obtain the unit cost of these requests, to estimate a % difference?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery's pricing model is based on how much bytes your query uses.

So if you want to query the results, than store the results as a BigQuery table. Set a destination table when you run your query.

There is no point of reloading from GCS a previous results. The cost will be the same, you just complicate this.

Comment: The results change each day, it doesnt make sense to create a table out of it. I am basically redownloading the same query dataset until some other condition is matched. Thus I might need to retry to query this particular query X times per day. Therefore I thought it would make more sense to store the results to Cloud Storage as it would be cheaper to load this data, so I dont have to query it from BigQuery. Doesn't that make sense?

Comment: Setup a dataset where tables automatically expire. You can store your table 24hours and could automatically expire.

Comment: Data stored in BigQuery are optimized for BigQuery, your CSVs have to be parsed then processed. It takes more times, no % to provide, but mathematically more!

Comment: Actually I noticed that if you query out rows from a table, the consumption count is the entire table size, unless your table is partitioned or you only query a selection of columns. I therefore don't have a solution yet to this problem. Reloading a set is then I think cheaper as GCS is cheaper.